# not able to check the radio button selected value in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got  4 radio buttons in view that i am binding these from model like this below

```
@model MVC.Models.DeleteModel
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Delete"))
{

   <div class=".editor-field">
       @Html.Label("Delete");
   </div>

   <div class =".editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsDeleteByItemChecked,"By Item")
       @Html.Label("By Item")
  </div>
    <div class =".editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsDeleteByVendorChecked,"By Vendor")
         @Html.Label("By Vendor")

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsCancelPageChecked,"Cancel Page")
         @Html.Label("Cancel Page")
  </div>
  <div class =".editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsDeleteByMemberChecked,"By Member")
       @Html.Label("By Member")
  </div>

    <div class=".editor-field">
           <input id="btnSubmitChanges" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>    
}
```

and this is my model

```
 public class DeleteModel
{

    public bool IsDeleteByItemChecked { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleteByVendorChecked { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleteByMemberChecked { get; set; }
    public bool IsCancelPageChecked { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Item")]
    public string ByItem { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Vendor")]
    public string ByVendor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Member")]
    public string ByMember { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cancel Page")]
    public string CancelPage { get; set; }

}
```

and this is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(DeleteModel deleteModel)
    {

        //some coding stuff

         //here i am checking the radio button for selected one 
        if (deleteModel.IsDeleteByItemChecked)
        {

            DeleteItem deleteByItemInsert = new DeleteItem();
            deleteByItemInsert.DeleteField = "ITEM";
            deleteByItemInsert.DeleteIndicator = char.MinValue;
            deleteByItemInsert.DeleteValue = itemDTO.ItemID;
        }
        if (deleteModel.IsDeleteByMemberChecked)
        {
            DeleteItem deleteByMemberInsert = new DeleteItem();
            deleteByMemberInsert.DeleteField = "MEMBER";
            deleteByMemberInsert.DeleteIndicator = char.MinValue;
            deleteByMemberInsert.DeleteValue = "";
        }
```

Problem is if i select the `first radio button` and then click the `submit button` its comes to first if condition inside the controller but `first if condition` is giving false ....

how can i check whether the radio button is selected or not in side controller

would any one pls have a solution for this...

another  problem is if i select the first radio button and then select the second radio button , I am not able to dis-select the first radio button how can i rectify this one ....

Answer (score 1):

The two issues are related.  By modifying your model slightly you will be able to group the radio buttons so that clicking on deselects the others as well as check the value that was selected.

First, modify your model to be:

```
public class DeleteModel
{

    public string DeleteBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Item")]
    public string ByItem { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Vendor")]
    public string ByVendor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Member")]
    public string ByMember { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cancel Page")]
    public string CancelPage { get; set; }

}
```

The first parameter of Html.RadioButtonFor() should be the property name you're using, and the second parameter should be the value of that specific radio button. Then they'll have the same name attribute value and the helper will select the given radio button when/if it matches the property value.

Continuing with the modifications to the DeleteModel class, this would make the view become:

```
  <div class =".editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.DeleteBy,"item")
       @Html.Label("By Item")
  </div>
    <div class =".editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.DeleteBy,"vendor")
         @Html.Label("By Vendor")

   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.DeleteBy,"page")
         @Html.Label("Cancel Page")
  </div>
  <div class =".editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.DeleteBy,"member")
       @Html.Label("By Member")
  </div>
```

Which would then be checked in the controller like so:

```
if (deleteModel.DeleteBy == "item")
{
    DeleteItem deleteByItemInsert = new DeleteItem();
    deleteByItemInsert.DeleteField = "ITEM";
    deleteByItemInsert.DeleteIndicator = char.MinValue;
    deleteByItemInsert.DeleteValue = itemDTO.ItemID;
}
if (deleteModel.DeleteBy == "member")
{
    DeleteItem deleteByMemberInsert = new DeleteItem();
    deleteByMemberInsert.DeleteField = "MEMBER";
    deleteByMemberInsert.DeleteIndicator = char.MinValue;
    deleteByMemberInsert.DeleteValue = "";
}
```